# Can you fix unintuitive completion hints in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I type something like Integer.toString and press "Ctrl+Space", it gives me the completion hint of Integer.toString(int arg0, int arg1), but I want it to write Integer.toString(int i, int radix) so that I know that the first argument is the number and the second one is the radix. Can you install some plugin that does that, instead of showing these unintuitive "arg0", "arg1" parameter names?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it uses the installed sources and/or javadoc to give the hint; try installing a proper set of javadocs?

Comment: @daniu how do I install that?

Comment: This might have something to do with the JDK you have set up and maybe even the Eclipse version. Setting a manual JDK8u152 in Neon completes the argument names appropriately without having to edit the JRE definition manually for me. Maybe try to add the javadocs.

Comment: You could write one yourself, the code would be pretty similar to this code completion plugin on GitHub: https://github.com/trylimits/Eclipse-Postfix-Code-Completion - it's a bit outdated no, but then again, so is Eclipse

Comment: @Pavel in your build dependencies, double-click a class file from the JDK (eg `Integer`). That should take you to the source file. If it doesn't, it gives you an option to associate a source file. A source zip you can use should be present in your JDK installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As daniu pointed out in the comments, Eclipse uses the javadoc to get the information. The argument names simply don't exist in the compiled JRE. I can confirm that in my workspace, javadoc is attached but no sources and the completion shows the correct names.

Eclipse should add the information on it's own, but if it does not for some reason, you can add it yourself.

In your project folder, you will see "JRE System Library [your Java version]". Inside that, there are a bunch of jars. Right click on each one and got to Properties -> Javadoc Location.  There you can input the javadoc location for the jar. In the case of Java 8, this is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ for all of them. If you use a different version, use a search engine of your choice to find the correct javadoc.

Comment: It seems like jdk9 that I have installed is causing problems. I tried to install netbeans yesterday and also had a problem installing it because I have java 9.

Comment: I had the same problem and confirm reinstall of the eclipse and JDK from another packages worked

Comment: Eclipse can also extract this information from the source code. That’s what happens automatically when using a jdk instead of a jre and the sources were not deselected in the installer. I actually never tried to get that information from javadoc and the idea of Eclipse having to fetch websites from the internet for the proposal doesn’t really convince me. So my suggestion is to install a JDK (if you haven’t already) and change the “JRE System Library” to the JDK. In JDK9, the source location has changed; if Eclipse doesn’t recognize it, adapting the path manually should not be so hard.